# Joomla Article Edit Backend no options show

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using joomla 3.7.5 and I login on the backend as an administrator and as super user.
I try to edit an article but I don't see the option for editing "images and link", "publishing options" etc of the article.
On the component's option I have set all options to "yes"
I have try it with tinyMCE, JCE, and no editor.

please help.

Christoforos